# Python3 SQLite row won't be removed on Ubuntu, but will be removed on Windows

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to remove a row in SQLite3, on windows it removes the row, but on Ubuntu it won't. I'm not sure what's causing it/how to fix it. Both systems are running Python 3.6.5, and I did not install SQLite3 with pip.

I'm running the following script, which creates a db.sqlite, creates a user table with (key, name) and inserts one user. Then it should remove it:

```py
import sqlite3

class DBHelper:
    def __init__(self, dbname="db.sqlite"):
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
        self.conn.set_trace_callback(print)

    def setup(self):
        stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (key text PRIMARY KEY, name text)"
        self.conn.execute(stmt)
        stmt = "INSERT INTO users (key, name) VALUES ('Acf233146328cea01fe9648acc3053fa', 125368500)"
        self.conn.execute(stmt)
        self.conn.commit()

    def delete_user(self, name, key):
        stmt = "DELETE FROM users WHERE name = (?) AND key = (?)"
        args = (name, key)
        self.conn.execute(stmt, args)
        self.conn.commit()

    def get_all(self):
        stmt = "SELECT name, key FROM users"
        return [x for x in self.conn.execute(stmt)]


def get_db():
    db = DBHelper()
    return db


name = 125368500
key = 'Acf233146328cea01fe9648acc3053fa'

print('Delete {0} {1}'.format(name, key))
db = get_db()
db.setup()
db.delete_user(name, key)
for user_data in db.get_all():
    print('{0} {1}'.format(user_data[0], user_data[1]))
```

On Ubuntu it returns (incorrect):

```
Delete 125368500 Acf233146328cea01fe9648acc3053fa
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (key text PRIMARY KEY, name text)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO users (key, name) VALUES ('Acf233146328cea01fe9648acc3053fa', 125368500)
COMMIT
BEGIN
DELETE FROM users WHERE name = (125368500) AND key = ('Acf233146328cea01fe9648acc3053fa')
COMMIT
SELECT name, key FROM users
125368500 Acf233146328cea01fe9648acc3053fa
```

On Windows it returns (correct):

```
Delete 125368500 Acf233146328cea01fe9648acc3053fa
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (key text PRIMARY KEY, name text)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO users (key, name) VALUES ('Acf233146328cea01fe9648acc3053fa', 125368500)
COMMIT
BEGIN
DELETE FROM users WHERE name = (125368500) AND key = ('Acf233146328cea01fe9648acc3053fa')
COMMIT
SELECT name, key FROM users
```

**Update**: So it seems like I'm experiencing a bug introduced in SQLite 3.11.0: https://sqlite.org/src/info/ef360601
And because Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS comes with [3.11.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/sqlite3) by default I am going to need to update the version.

**Update 2**: Updating the typings by changing name to string fixes it as well. Seems to be the same case in the sqlite bug report.

Comment: There is no exception, just does not delete row?!

Comment: @MauroBaraldi not sure what you mean by that? If you're asking if it does not throw an exception: correct, it just doesn't delete the row.

Comment: Does database file the same in both systems? Is there no exception?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi It creates one from scratch, so I'd assume they're the same. No exceptions.

Comment: the code you have does not guarantee new sqlite file is created, you can explicitly delete one at start if the script if it exists and then run on each of the systems. this is the only part that may be different across the machines.

Comment: another way to test is to run in-memory database, this should isolate an error from disk-related potential causes

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak thanks, but I found the bug already. Had to do with the version of which ubuntu 16.04.4 TLS ships SQLite with as you can read in my updates.

Comment: a very subtle, but sevete bug, indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Because I was using Ubuntu 16.04 with SQLite it ships with version 3.11.0, which has the following bug: https://sqlite.org/src/info/ef360601

To solve this, I need to use correct types when creating the table/inserting before I can delete the rows.

The fixed code:

```py
import sqlite3

class DBHelper:
    def __init__(self, dbname="db.sqlite"):
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
        self.conn.set_trace_callback(print)

    def setup(self):
        stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (key text PRIMARY KEY, name text)"
        self.conn.execute(stmt)
        stmt = "INSERT INTO users (key, name) VALUES ('Acf233146328cea01fe9648acc3053fa', '125368500')"
        self.conn.execute(stmt)
        self.conn.commit()

    def delete_user(self, name, key):
        stmt = "DELETE FROM users WHERE name = (?) AND key = (?)"
        args = (name, key)
        self.conn.execute(stmt, args)
        self.conn.commit()

    def get_all(self):
        stmt = "SELECT name, key FROM users"
        return [x for x in self.conn.execute(stmt)]


def get_db():
    db = DBHelper()
    return db


name = '125368500'
key = 'Acf233146328cea01fe9648acc3053fa'

print('Delete {0} {1}'.format(name, key))
db = get_db()
db.setup()
db.delete_user(name, key)
for user_data in db.get_all():
    print('{0} {1}'.format(user_data[0], user_data[1]))
```