# sqlite3 fetchone() returns sqlite3.Row type on Windows, but a tuple on Mac

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm running the same code on MacOS and on WindowsOS

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('rocbot.sqlite')
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select * from <tablename> where name = <value>')
s_obj = c.fetchone()
conn.close()

type(s_obj)
```

On my Mac, type returns `<class 'tuple'>` whereas on my Windows computer, it returns `<class 'sqlite3.Row'>`. Why is the behaviour different on both computers? What can I do to the code to make it run correctly with both computers? I need the return to be a tuple.

Mac's sqlite_version is 3.31.1

Windows' sqlite_version is 3.29.0 [Update: still doesn't work after upgrading to 3.33.0]

Comment: Does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844971/python3-sqlite-row-wont-be-removed-on-ubuntu-but-will-be-removed-on-windows Check all the versions, both of the modules and the SQLite3 itself.

Comment: Mac's version is 3.31.1, and Windows was 3.29.0. I upgraded the windows one to 3.33.0 but the issue persists

Comment: If you want a tuple, why are you doing `conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row`?  If you leave `row_factory` unset you will get tuples automatically.